# Can't add button to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I tried the following code to the Webform.aspx page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnShowAssignLecturer" runat="server" 
        onclick="btnShowAssignLecturer_Click" Text="Assign Lecturer To Room" />
```

It says: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'ctl00_head_btnShowAssignLecturer' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

When I do that, I get another error. Not quite sure what to do.

Master page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="AllsWellHospital.Front_End.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <h1>All Wells Hospital</h1>
      <p>
      <asp:Label ID="DateDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </p>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>   
    <link id="Link1" href="/Styles/StyleSheet2.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
    body
    {
     background-color:#d0e4fe;   
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
     <div id="topContent">
     <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="WebForm1.aspx" Text="Web form.aspx"  Value="Upload SP10"></asp:MenuItem>
             </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
    </div>




    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Webform.aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Front_End/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AllsWellHospital.Front_End.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
        Text="Course Report"></asp:Label>

         <asp:Button ID="btnShowAssignLecturer" runat="server" 
        onclick="btnShowAssignLecturer_Click" Text="Assign Lecturer To Room" />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button needs to be within a **form tag** and currently it isn't. Do you really want to place the button within the **head** portion of your form? Why not just add another content area for your main content. Try doing something like this:

**Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="AllsWellHospital.Front_End.MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<h1>All Wells Hospital</h1>
  <p>
  <asp:Label ID="DateDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </p>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>   
<link id="Link1" href="/Styles/StyleSheet2.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
body
{
 background-color:#d0e4fe;   
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
 <div id="topContent">
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Items>
  <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="WebForm1.aspx" Text="Web form.aspx"  Value="Upload SP10"></asp:MenuItem>
         </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
</div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



</form>
```

**Your aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Front_End/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AllsWellHospital.Front_End.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
    Text="Course Report"></asp:Label>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    onclick="btnShowAssignLecturer_Click" Text="Assign Lecturer To Room" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

A button must be placed inside of a server managed `<form>` tag in order for the post to actually do anything in the ASP pipeline.

However, your content place holder `Content1` is inside the `<head>` tag of the master page, where `<form>` is invalid. You need to rethink your master page so that this content does not live inside of the `<head>` element, and include a `<form runat='server'>` surrounding your form.

You may have meant to use the HTML 5 `<header>` element, which is distintly different than the normal `<head>` element.